# Why isn't this React POST request sending data to server?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, post

Here is my code:

Search.js
(function):

```
async downloadFile(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        fetch('/download', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', Accept: 'application/json' },
            body: JSON.stringify({
              fileId: "1qupvie1LqNdLj-1TZNu3x6-4bT411C4F2YYGSfpc7yk"
            })
          }) 
    }
```

(JSX):
These are React Bootstrap classes.

```
<Form onSubmit = {this.downloadFile} >
  <Button type = "submit" className = "btn-primary export-btn"> Export </Button>
</Form>
```

Node.js Server (running on 8080):

```
app.post("/download", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body.fileId)
})
```

Why is the console.log of the req showing up as undefined? I need some help.

Things to note:

1. The downloadFile(event) function is bound to this.
2. The server is working fine, and express is set up properly.
3. The proxy in the package.json file is set to "http://localhost:8080/", and the server is receiving the request. Just throwing an error.
4. This is the error I'm getting. "TypeError: Cannot read property 'fileId' of undefined"
5. I don't think the React Bootstrap elements are the problem - I used them in another project using this same exact method and it worked. Besides, the POST request is being sent, it's just not receiving the body element of fileId.

Comment: can you please show the whole related code at server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably missing `app.use(express.json())`, it's a middleware that parses incoming requests that have the Content-Type of json

Comment: That's a really good point. Let me see if adding that works.

Comment: Yup. This worked. Except it was body-parser module I forgot to set the json to. Thank you!